# volume augmented garch(1,1) model in matlab

Tags: risk, garch

Actually I want to add volume traded of a stock in my Garch(1,1) model to forecast the volatility.In Matlab I can specify the model as garch(1,1) and then use estimate and forecast commands.But I am not sure how to specify my volume augmented garch(1,1) model in Matlab.

Any help on this would be very appreciated.